# Mouse OnDrag event on GDI graphics object

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, gdi+

I have a simple question about mouse events.

I have a WinForms application and I used the GDI+ graphics object
to draw simple shape, a circle.

Now what I want to do is to drag this shape with the mouse.

So when the user is moving the mouse, when the left button is still pressed
I want to move the object.

my question is how to detect if the user is still pressing on the mouse's left button?
I know that there is no onDrag event in winforms.
any ideas?

Comment: But you have onMouseDown and onMouseUp, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this very simplified example. It doesn't cover many aspects of GDI+ drawing, but gives you an idea how to handle mouse event's in winforms.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsExamples
{
    public partial class DragCircle : Form
    {


        private bool bDrawCircle;
        private int circleX;
        private int circleY;
        private int circleR = 50;

        public DragCircle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InvalidateCircleRect()
        {
            this.Invalidate(new Rectangle(circleX, circleY, circleR + 1, circleR + 1));
        }

        private void DragCircle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            circleX = e.X;
            circleY = e.Y;
            bDrawCircle = true;
            this.Capture = true;
            this.InvalidateCircleRect();
        }

        private void DragCircle_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            bDrawCircle = false;
            this.Capture = false;
            this.InvalidateCircleRect();
        }

        private void DragCircle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (bDrawCircle)
            {
                this.InvalidateCircleRect(); //Invalidate region that was occupied by circle before move
                circleX = e.X;
                circleY = e.Y;
                this.InvalidateCircleRect(); //Add to invalidate region the rectangle that circle will occupy after move.
            }
        }

        private void DragCircle_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bDrawCircle)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), circleX, circleY, circleR, circleR);
            }
        }


    }
}
```